# Deploying a Play! Framework app

Tags: playframework

After the command `play run`, how does Play get started as a host on the machine? Does it run apache, tomcat or such behind the scenes?

If I want to get my app (built using play! framework) to be hosted on, for example, apache, is it going to be an easy task?

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, play can be used in conjunction with apache setup as a reverse proxy (see put your app in production), or as standalone running with the netty server included in Play!. If the answers satisfy your question, accept one of them.

Answer (score 14):

It runs [netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) behind the scenes. If you want to host it under a servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty, just do this from your project folder :

```
play war -o /tmp
```

and you will see your project's war file in the `/tmp` folder. Stick it under `webapps` folder of Tomcat or Jetty and you should be good to go. You can front-end the servlet container with Apache/httpd just like you'd do with any such set up (i.e. the fact that your war came from Playframework will not make any difference in front-ending part).

Answer (score 11):

Play normally runs using its own server, the `play.server.Server` class. Accessing a Play app via another server such as Apache will never be any faster than accessing the Play server directly, but if you want to do it for other reasons, see [Put your application in production](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/production).

Comment: How can I invoke this server from withing my Java/Scala code? (without using Play)

Answer (score 5):

Just for clarity, as of play2 there is no longer any official support for packaging your project as a war file and furthermore it doesnt look like support will be coming back anytime soon.

Play2 now comes with its own webserver based on Netty and to deploy you can use "play stage" to package up you project and run it in place using the "target/start" command.

If your going to host your project on a server without Play2 installed, just use the "sbt compile stage" command first which will bundle the necessary dependencies for you.

There is however an unofficial effort at https://github.com/dlecan/play2-war-plugin if your still interested in deploying to a Servlet 3.0 or 2.5 container (Tomcat 6/7, Jetty 7/8/9, JBoss 5/6/ etc) I havent used this personally but I have heard good things about it.